# Tokenizer and Filter : Split the Data in Elastic search Setting

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I have Using following Setting For Split the String in My index.

```
   {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "filter_stop_word": {
          "type": "stop"
        },
        "custom_unique": {
          "type": "unique"
        },
        "custom_shingle": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "token_separator": "",
          "max_shingle_size": "3",
          "filler_token": ""
        },
        "filter_word_delimiter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "en_us": {
          "filter": [
            "filter_stop_word",
            "filter_word_delimiter",
            "custom_shingle",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Input : "Treeviewcontrol is one of the tool"

If I give above input to my setting, it will produce following output:

[ tree, treeview,treeviewcontrol,view, viewcontrol,Viewcontrolone, controlone,tool ]

But My require output is Given below - 
tree,
view,
control,
treeview,
viewcontrol,
one,
tool,

Don't join after whitespace token.
Any one Help Me ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the camel case tokenizer , you can break the tokens based on case -

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/  -d '{
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "camelFilter" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : 0,
               "patterns" : [
                  "(\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}+)",
                  "(\\d+)"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer" : {
            "camel" : {
               "tokenizer" : "pattern",
               "filter" : [ "camelFilter", "lowercase" ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'

curl 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=camel' -d 'qboxElasticsearchServiceProvider'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "qbox",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 32,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "elasticsearch",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 32,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "service",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 32,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "provider",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 32,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

LINK - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Plz check my input in Your Analyzer.. I checked. {tree,View,control,one,control] where is treeview and viewcontrol??